# Dummy Code with Multiple Conditional Statements to return multiple options in R

Tags: r

I need to dummmy code my data into three groups by creating a column that does the following:

0 = if jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode += "101545", "101318", "100897", "100895", "100891", "100885", "100884", "100880", "100875", "100873" AND jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date += NA

1 = if jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode = "101545", "101318", "100897", "100895", "100891", "100885", "100884", "100880", "100875", "100873" AND jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date != NA

2= everything else

Currently have tried

```
> jobentrydat_alltechs$typeofterm <- if(jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode ==
> c("101545", "101318", "100897", "100895", "100891", "100885",
> "100884", "100880", "100875", "100873") &
>           jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date == is.na(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date)) {
>             print("0")
>           } else if (jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode == c("101545", "101318", "100897", "100895", "100891", "100885", "100884", "100880",
> "100875", "100873") &
>             jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date != is.na(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date)) {
>               print("1")
>             } else {
>               print("2")
>             }
```

I have also attempted to use ifelse, but I'm not as familiar with that. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but this Tuesday feels like a second Monday.

Warning messages:

```
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode, c("101545", "101318",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In if (jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode == c("101545", "101318", "100897",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
5: In `==.default`(jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode, c("101545", "101318",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
6: In if (jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode == c("101545", "101318", "100897",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conditional.return <- function (bool1, bool2) {
    if (bool1 & bool2) return (0)
    else if (bool1 & !(bool2)) return (1)
    else return (2)
}

cond1 <- jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode %in% c("101545", "101318", "100897", "100895", "100891", "100885", "100884", "100880", "100875", "100873")
cond2 <- is.na(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date)

jobentrydat_alltechs$typeofterm <- mapply(conditional.return, cond1, cond2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
jobentrydat_alltechs$typeofterm <- ifelse((jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode %in% 
    c("101545","101318", "100897", "100895", "100891", "100885","100884", 
      "100880", "100875", "100873") & is.na(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date)), "0",  
    ifelse((jobentrydat_alltechs$Jobcode %in% c("101545", "101318", "100897",
           "100895", "100891", "100885", "100884", "100880","100875", 
           "100873") & != is.na(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date)), "1", "2"))
```

The only difference is that I changed `==` to `%in%` and then used 2 `ifelse` statements.